# How do we maximize core and winding losses in an electromagnet (and calculate them) for variable DC input?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnet, losses

**Bigger Picture:**

Imagine a magnet approaching the solenoid with some initial constant velocity on \$v_0\$ on x axis. The approaching magnet will induce an EMF and induced current in solenoid. We want to maximize the power loss so that the solenoid acts as a brake. We intend to do so by maximizing the power losses in the solenoid (both winding and core).

**Technical Setup:**

Most of the time we deal with minimizing copper and core losses in an electromagnet. Let us now consider an electromagnet with a core: the shape, size, material etc. and all the other variables are left free for design.

Given an electromagnet in which the winding is supplied with some variable DC input current and voltage, and their values can be determined by two given functions over time \$t: V(t)\$ and \$I(t)\$. The maximum input voltage and current are 10s of volts and at most 10 A. We can thus simply determine the value of input power:

\$P(t)= V(t).I(t)\$

**Technical Objective:**

We need to maximize the power losses in the electromagnet (in form of eddy currents etc.) in terms of percentage w.r.t. to total input power to the winding. How do we achieve this?

**Question 1:** To maximize the core losses what shape, size, material, etc. for the core do we need? Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core) mentions: > If the core is electrically conductive, the changing magnetic field induces circulating loops of current in it, called eddy currents, due to electromagnetic induction. The loops flow perpendicular to the magnetic field axis. The energy of the currents is dissipated as heat in the resistance of the core material. The power loss is proportional to the area of the loops and inversely proportional to the resistivity of the core material.

So should we as a rule of. thumb choose a highly conductive solid core (soft iron with maximum diameter in case of a cylindrical shape)?

How do we deal with this rigorously from an engineering point of view (both design and calculating the power losses)? Can we achieve losses of over 75% (of input power)?

**Question 2:** What kind of winding parameters do we need ((1). gauge of wire, (2) number of turns (3) shape of solenoid) to maximize the winding losses?

Comment: *We need to maximize the power losses in the electromagnet* <-- why?

Comment: I genuinely want to know what combination would maximize heat losses. in joules heating devices we do that right. i want to know how much can be done in this scenario.

Comment: i asked on physics forum didn't get any response at all thus deleted it and posting it here..

Comment: Since magnetic field strength and size is not constrained, the trivial solution is a resistor of R = Vmax/Imax which maximizes loss P = Vmax*Imax.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks but I don't get it can you please elaborate (not electrical background).. regarding core what resistor?

Comment: A DC current = zero eddy current... only AC does that.  A static magnetic field does zero work; otherwise transformers could work at DC!  A transformer at DC is nothing more than a fancy heater.  Now what determines that heating?

Comment: thanks. when I say DC I mean the magnitude of DC can change without changing direction.. so its not static (please correct me if i am wrong)? For static magnitude DC i think its \$I^2R\$ but this is not a static case right ?

Comment: Let's take a step back. What are you /really/ after here?  Do you actually mean induction heating (non-contact heating of a conductive workpiece by alternating magnetic field)?

Comment: an external field (say by an approaching magnet) generates an induced EMF in a solenoid. The feild's magnitude changes with time. So does the induced EMF in solenoid. I intend to maximize the losses in the solenoid due to induced emf and induced current.

Comment: When the other Tim is asking what you're _really_ doing, he's seeing that you're asking a screwy question, and he (and I) wants to make sure that when you get an answer it won't just maximize your core losses, but it'll _also_ achieve whatever your (currently mysterious) _actual goals_ are.

Comment: Core losses are an AC phenomenon, and the "ideal" bulk resistivity of the core will depend on the geometry of the magnetic circuit, the frequency of the applied power, and -- if it's changing -- the dynamic behavior of how the magnetic circuit is changing.  So -- we need more details.

Comment: @TimWescott nothing mysterious here! :) assume an approaching magnet with constant initial velocity towards solenoid, that introduces an EMF and current in solenoid.. i want to know how to maximize that current/power loss (I assumed that introducing a core would do the task).. but as the answer states below that would work for an AC (just like you pointed)... So am back to winding losses.. essentially how to make a solenoid that maximizes power losses.. There are videos of magnet slowing down when approaching a solenoid.. similar (most efficient version of that).. with mathematical treatment.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with this additional information about your problem.

Comment: And -- **Why** do you want to maximize power loss?  Braking?  If you're _really_ interested in a magnetic brake, then _say so_.

Comment: yes. Sorry I thought I will ask the core technical part of the question. Due apologies. Edited the Q.

Comment: Have you ever done the experiment where you drop a cylindrical magnet through a non-ferrous hollow tube (copper or aluminum both work well)?  The magnet drops considerably slower than free-fall due to the magnetic field inducing currents in the tube.  You can get quite a bit of braking just from the metal tube.  No coils involved.

Comment: I understand (I just mentioned that experiment above). The thing is I would prefer the coil setup as there is only 1 circuit or path for current to follow and understand the optimal case mathematically (by some approximation) if possible.

Comment: What material is the magnet made of? Are its dimensions fixed, or can we adjust the shape for best effect? You say the magnet 'approaches' the solenoid. Can it go inside it? Will the solenoid/electromagnet be used for any other purpose than slowing down the magnet?

Comment: How can we know the power loss if we don't know the magnetic field strength, dimensions of magnet and coil, and mass?  In general, an electromagnetic brake applies a force proportional to velocity, so the peak power is simply whatever the initial velocity and magnetic field strength develop, the coil's resistance should be minimal (e.g. solid copper, as closely fitted to the magnet as possible), and velocity decreases exponentially with time. Voltage and current are not involved as no terminals are connected.

Comment: @BruceAbbott the magnet can have any shape as long as it has the same mass.. yes the solenoid can be designed so the magnet can go inside it.. the optimum braking mechanism would be the one that maximizes power loss.. so other than causing the power loss and braking the pair don't do anything else.

Comment: @TimWilliams Relative power loss as I mentioned earlier. Percentage of induced current and voltage vs. power loss. Please consider an N52 magnet.

Comment: @student0 Is this more hypothetical or do you have something specific in mind? I mean in terms of dimensions of magnet, voltages, forces and masses involved etc.

Comment: I want a braking mechanism but with maximum power losses or heating. I want to construct it eventually if I get the generic idea what would be the best design. Thus, other than mass of the magnet, its initial velocity and its type (N52) everything else is open for design. but i don't seem to get much out here (in terms of specifics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems based on your comments that you just want to stop the magnet.  Whether there is a core or not is irrelevant.

Let's consider the case of a magnet entering into a coil of wire wound around a plastic bobbin.  A cross section is shown below.

[image]

In order to stop the magnet, you need to make the magnet transfer its kinetic energy into the coil.

The coil is an inductor and therefore it can store energy.

$$E(t) = \frac12i(t)^2L(x(t))$$

Where...

- E(t) is the stored energy.
- i(t) is the coil current.
- L(x(t)) is the coil inductance.  Note that L varies which varies with magnet position x.  Usually, it will vary with the square of the depth to which the magnet is inserted into the coil.

We can also say that...

$$V(x(t)) = L(x) * \frac{di}{dt}$$

Where...

- di/dt is the rate of change of current in the coil.
- V(x(t)) is the inductor voltage (induced by motion of the magnet).

The inductance will be proportional to the square of the number of turns.  So we may write...

$$ L(x(t)) = \beta(x(t)) * N^2 $$

Where...

- Beta(x(t)) is a function that depends on the position of the magnet relative to the coil, the geometry of the magnet and coil, their relative position.  Usually, Beta varies proportional to x^2 and proportionally to the permeability of the magnet material.
- N is the number of turns of wire.

As the magnet enters the bobbin the field lines move through the wires with a perpendicular component.  As they move it will induce a voltage in the wires.

$$V(x(t)) = \alpha(x(t)) * N * \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Where...

- Alpha(x(t)) is a "coupling factor" that depends on the position of the magnet relative to the coil, the geometry of the magnet and coil, their relative position, and the strength of the magnet.
- V(x(t)) is the induced voltage.
- dx/dt is the velocity of the magnet as it enters.
- x(t) is the position of the magnet relative to the solenoid.

An important thing to note is that all other things being equal, if you use thinner wire but pack more turns into the same volume, then alpha(x(t)) should be largely unaffected, but V will increase proportional to the number of turns.

**Now to maximizing braking...**

- Note that current must flow in a loop.  So, the ends of the solenoid wires must be part of a circuit.  If the wires were open, you would not transfer energy to the coil.
- Secondly, any resistance in series with the coil will reduce the amount of current that builds up, and therefore reduce the energy.  Ideally, we want the resistance as low as possible.

In the case of shorting the coil ends together, assuming no coil resistance, a fixed motion of the magnet, and combining the above equation we get...

$$E = \frac12\int \frac{\alpha(x(t))}{\beta(x(t))N}\frac{di}{dt}$$

The alpha and beta terms just depend on the geometry.  We don't even need to find them to know that if all other things are equal, the maximum braking occurs with a low number of turns and low resistance.  Both of those factors are minimized by just using a metal tube (thicker tube walls are better here).

Also note that alpha and beta are probably going to be pretty hard to calculate by hand.  Normally one would build a model in some EM solver tool and calculate them that way.

Comment: thank you. I feel guilty for saying it since i am in debt of the amount of effort you put in this. but braking with [maximizing power loss] is one of the primary objective. The optimal point where that happens. This does address the braking part. but low number of turns and low resistance also implies low power loss. I am looking for an optimal balance of both. please do not take it wrongly as i appreciate the effort that went into this.

Comment: is it possible to address the power loss factor too?

Comment: @student0 This answer provides the solution (once you dig through it): Move the magnet through a hollow cylinder (no coil or core needed) of a material with highest possible conductivity, e.g. a hollow Al or Cu cylinder. Your assertion that low resistivity works worse is false. Even a superconducting cylinder will stop the magnet (think of superconducting magnetic levitation).

Comment: @tobalt you missed the point about losses. That was part of the original Q. I understand this would work but the losses dissipated in terms of heat (which i think are \$I^2R\$) will be minimum as the resistance would be minimum. am i correct?

Comment: @student0 No I think you are wrong.. The current generated in a low resistivity material will be higher. And the losses scale with current **squared** as you have properly stated. (The superconductor might be a special edge case here). See demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh0bbW6S3BY

Comment: ok. i think i understand. so if I were still (for some silly reason) was intent on using a coil I should use a coil with minimum turns (best case 1 turn) and maximum gauge to maximize the losses?

Comment: @student0 A coil (with thin isolated wire turns) will almost not work at all unless you short it, at which point it becomes essentially a bad cylinder.

Comment: thank you. i understand it completely.

Comment: @student0 If this answer was helpful for you, please take the time to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to maximize eddy current losses...

- Laminated cores reduce losses, so don't use them.
- Cores made of magnetic powder with an insulating binder material reduce losses.
- Solid conductive metal cores maximize losses. For example, a solid iron core.

But note that...

- For a DC current the core losses will be zero.
- For a very slowly changing current the core losses will still be very close to zero.

The main thing that will be dissipating heat in a solenoid with a DC current through it is the resistance of the wires that are wound around the core.

In fact, if the solenoid is not moving and you are putting a DC current into it, then all of the input power is turning into heat via the winding resistance.

Also note that the current doesn't need to change direction to have an AC component. For example, you could have:

$$I = 5~\mathrm{A}+4~\mathrm{A}\cdot\sin(2\cdot\pi\cdot f\cdot t)$$

In this case the current would vary between 1 A and 9 A at frequency f. The current never completely changes direction but has an AC component of 4 A.

Comment: Thank you. Assuming the induced current is due to an approaching magnet with single axis motion, say travelling on x axis towards a solenoid on x axis (with some initial velocity \$v_0\$ the DC approximation is correct right (yes the direction will change if the magnet passes through the solenoid if it has an air core but that is not the case)? So is there a way to convert the induced EMF/current into an AC current to maximize eddy losses it that case?

Comment: and if still eddy losses would be insignificant in the case above what should I do the maximize copper losses? there are so many variables to consider: (1) wire gauge (2) number of turns (3) shape of solenoid. Is there a way approximate generic idea what should be done to maximize copper losses for some initial velocity ?

Comment: A picture/diagram showing your setup with the position of the magnet coil and core would be helpful.

Comment: please imagine solenoid at origin and magnet traveling from -ve x axis direction towards +ve x axis direction. both concentric with cross section on x axis. is that clearer ?